# png image saved in mysql database, doesn't fully show on browser

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

PHP codes of index.php

```php
<?php
    include("connection.php");
    $sql = "SELECT prod_cost, prod_name, prod_image FROM products";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    
    //free result from memory
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    //close connection
    mysqli_close($con);
     
?>
```

image is read in src"" on the second line of the snippet below. Everything works but only half the image shows.

```html
<div class="col-1" onclick="location.href='item1.html';" style="cursor: pointer;">
  <img src="data:image/ppg;charset=utf8;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row[0]['prod_image'])?> " alt="Rooster Chicken #18">
  <h4><?php echo $row[0]['prod_name']; ?></h4>
  <p>$ <?php echo $row[0]['prod_cost']; ?> &nbsp;  <strike> $17.80 </strike></p>
</div>
```

[image]

The image was added directly to the database with

```sql
INSERT INTO products(prod_name, prod_stock,prod_cost,prod_image)
VALUES ('Rooster Chicken #18',100,17.65,LOAD_FILE('C:/xampp/htdocs/SNS/Images/products/rooster18.png'));
```

NB: PHP snippets shown above are from the same page called index,php

Comment: What mime type is `image/ppg`? Did you mean `image/png`?

Comment: What MySQL data type is `prod_image`? Also, you have a trailing space character in your `<img>` tag `src` attribute that probably shouldn't be there

Comment: Does it work if you specify a known, valid image URL? Is there some other CSS that is obscuring the image?

Comment: Hey ... What is the size of your image on the Disk? if it's more than 1MB, you might need to update max_allowed_packet setting.

Comment: thanks @Phil, The problem was the data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify your data type for `prod_image` column. Make sure what you save via `LOAD_FILE('C:/xampp/htdocs/SNS/Images/products/rooster18.png')` has enough space/size to store the complete image. I've used your code and it is working fine in my side(please change data:image/ppg to `data:image/png`).

FYI below table structure is used:
[image]

Comment: Out of interest, does your own testing show the same problem as OP if you use `image/ppg`?

Comment: It shows image correctly even I keep image/ppg

Comment: thanks for the help brother. Apparently the data type I chose on my database was to small to even support my image. I previously used "BLOB", now I use "longblob"...Also changed this 'data:image/png' - but that wasn't the actual cause because that was me attempting to fix the issue beforehand, forgot to change it back. Thank you for your time friend.